# Custom template for each page

Tags: page-template

I am creating multiple pages in Wordpress. I understand I can style these with page.php. Is there any way I can style specific pages with custom templates? So for example if I had page About Us I would want a sidebar that has links to our profiles. If I had page Contact Us I would want a sidebar that has links for emailing us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a few way you can do that:

- [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display) - each page with is own theme file using page-{ID/slug}.php
- [Custom  Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) - Individual Pages can be set to use a specific custom Page Template from the edit screen.

but if you are just looking to change whats on the sidebar then there are a few plugins that can help you with that:

- [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) -  lets you control on which pages widgets appear.
- [Dynamic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/) - lets you dynamicly place the widgets on WordPress pages.

and there are even plugins that let you display the whole sidebar on a page to page basis:

- [Sidebar Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-generator/)
- [Per Page Sidebars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/per-page-sidebars/)
- [Custom sidebars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-sidebars/)

Comment: Man, talk about thorough!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display). When you edit the page, you will be able to chose the template you want it to display in.